# counting lower and uppercase characters in haskell

Tags: haskell

Im a beginner to haskell and I've tried to create a function which counts the numbers of a character in a string. The problem I have is that I am only able to count either the number of occurences of a uppercase or a lowercase character. I want to count both of them. E.g. For the string Mum the result for counting m should be 2.

My function right now looks like this:

```
import Data.Char
countList :: [Char] -> Char -> Int
countList str c = length $ filter (== c) str
```

What would your suggestions on solving this be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import Data.Char (toUpper)

countChar :: Char -> [Char] -> Int
countChar char  = length . filter (\c -> toUpper c == toUpper char)


countChar 's' "Stdudents" => 2
countChar 'S' "Sstudents" => 3
countChar 'S' "$tudent$$" => 0
```

Given a character 'char', filter the entire string for any character whose uppercase matches the uppercase of 'char'. Feed the new filtered string to the 'length' function to get the total count.

Answer (score 1):

Just transform all to lowercase:

```
import Data.Char
countList :: [Char] -> Char -> Int
countList str c = length $ filter (== toLower c) $ map toLower str
```

You can also use just use `fold`, here a ghci example:

```
Prelude Data.Char> let countList = \str c -> foldl (\x y -> x + if ((toLower y) == (toLower c)) then 1 else 0) 0 str
Prelude Data.Char> countList "AAaabCC" 'a'
4
```

Answer (score 1):

A neat way to obtain the `toUpper c == toUpper char` comparison is to use the `on` combinator:

```
import Data.Function

countChar char = length . filter (on (==) toUpper char)
```

Comment: love the use of "on".